# Managed switch: make port communicate on two VLANs

Tags: linux, networking, vlan, netplan

I'm trying my best to have the following scenario.

VLAN1: All of my WiFi and non-IoT devices

VLAN2: All of the IoT devices including Raspberry Pi manager running Linux.

I want to make it possible to have Raspberry Pi manager communicate in both VLANs. But other VLAN2 devices are not allowed to communicate with VLAN1 (and vice versa).

[Schematic of wanted network setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPRLA.png)

I've tried setting the Raspberry Pi manager port as unmanaged in VLAN1 and as managed in VLAN2. I can then communicate with the Raspberry Pi manager on VLAN1 but pinging it from VLAN2 device is not possible.

I'm using 802.1q vlan and Raspberry Pi manager is aware of the vlan with id 2.

My managed switch is: TL-SG108E (L2 switch)

My current netplan config:

```
network:
version: 2
ethernets:
    eth0:
        dhcp4: true
vlans:
    eth0.2:
        id: 2
        link: eth0
        addresses: [192.168.179.1/24]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don’t know much this switch. What do you mean by managed port ? The datasheet of the switch doesn’t mention VLAN handling. What can be setup about it ? The use of 2 VLAN seems ok, but I would put the Raspberry on both since it should communicate with all nodes.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer sorry, I meant port on a managed switch. I can setup PVID and if the port is tagged or untagged in specific VLAN.

Comment: Then I would use all nodes on ports tagged with the adequate VLAN, excepted the Raspberry on a trunked port then it can be on both VLAN.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer so, tagging every other device on VLAN2 but not the Raspberry?

| VLAN1: Untagged P1 (network), Untagged P2 (raspberry) |
VLAN2: Untagged P2, Tagged P3-P8  |

Like that?

Comment: The Raspberry on  trunk port means that it receives everything TAGGED. Then the Raspberry can be on both VLAN. With untagged port put on a VLAN (is the switch support VLAN), the node can’t talk to other VLAN and doesn’t have to process 802.1q.